# Selecting a HTML button in Excel VBA that does not have an id

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Been working on this issue for a day now.  I have a webform that you have 1 set of standard data, and then you enter line items for a purchase requisition; I am trying to enter all data in Excel and use VBA to transfer it to the site.  I am getting stuck at how to "update part" (the text on the button that I need to click to add another line item on the webpage).  I have also tried the send key method to Shift Tab into the correct location (just normal shifting runs into an error with one of the fields).  I am fine with any solution working, this is my first attempt at linking Excel to HTML so it's been fun.

From what I can find the button does not have an id so I have not been successful in calling it.

Here is my code (with the web url deleted):

```
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim oHTML_Element1 As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
Dim aURL As String
Dim nodeList As Object


On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = URL Can't be Shared
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.Navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document
Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("a[onlick*='UpdatePartRow']")

HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("I1")
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("I2")

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For


    HTMLDoc.all.reason.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1") ' selects the reason for the requisition

    HTMLDoc.all.Comments.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2") ' selects the comments to purchasing

    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").getElementsByTagName("select")("RequiredMonth").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3")
    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").FireEvent ("onchange")

    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").getElementsByTagName("select")("RequiredDay").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B4")
    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").FireEvent ("onchange")

    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").getElementsByTagName("select")("RequiredYear").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B5")
    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").FireEvent ("onchange")

    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").getElementsByTagName("select")("CommodityMain").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B9")
    HTMLDoc.forms("_PurchaseRequisition").FireEvent ("onchange") 'Selects the commodity group

    HTMLDoc.all.Quantity.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B11")
    HTMLDoc.all.Description.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B12")
    HTMLDoc.all.ChargedDepartment.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B13")
    HTMLDoc.all.SubJobNumber.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B14")
    HTMLDoc.all.AccountNumber.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B15")
    HTMLDoc.all.UnitPrice.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B16")
    HTMLDoc.all.CommodityMainSub.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B17")


    Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("a[onlick*='UpdatePartRow']")

    nodeList.Item(0).Click
    nodeList.Item(0).FireEvent "onclick"



Next


' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

For the login portion I modified code from: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html#ZiqYAtAQMHzl7x1k.99

That works perfectly, so does entering the fields.

The segment of HTML that is associated with this button is:

```
<a onclick="UpdatePartRow();
chkKeepSubmitPR();

return false;" href=""></a>

<a onclick="var doc = window.document.forms[0];
    UpdatePartRow();
    chkKeepSubmitPR();
if (doc.OrgMatrixYes.value == &quot;Y&quot;) {
    VerifyDeptOrgMatrix();
}


return false;" href=""><img src="/Web/purchreq.nsf/UpdatePart.gif?OpenImageResource" width="72" height="25" border="0"></a>
```

I am taking this on because this system is a pain.  I could just have multiple macros and have the user hit the button between each line item, but I want to try to offer a full solution.  I am a mechanical engineer by trade and my coding experience is limited to what I have picked up on making tools to ease my job.  Any help or suggestions would be super helpful.  If there is more info needed, please let me know and I can try to help anyway I can.  Thank you!

Update:  I have tried (See Code) to make the changes that have been suggested.  I am still a fairly complete newbie when it comes to coding, so please bear with me and thank you for trying to teach me!

Comment: Are you sure it's a button, it has an <a> tag.  You could try to get the item, and then invoke its click method using `.fireevent("click")`

Comment: Can you provide an URL?

Comment: @QHarr, it is a company specific URL that has data on purchasing projects, for several reasons I cannot share it.

Comment: ok... well give the below a try and let me know :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `a` tag elements there with an `onclick`

You can get both with attribute = value CSS selector using `"*"` *contains* operator to search for a substring in the attribute value

```
a[onclick*='UpdatePartRow']
```

You can grab both with `querySelectorAll` method of HTMLDocument object

```
Dim nodeList As Object
Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("a[onclick*='UpdatePartRow']")
```

The two matches, for your sample, are as follows:

index 0

```
<a onclick="UpdatePartRow(); chkKeepSubmitPR(); return false;" href="">
```

index 1

```
<a onclick="var doc = window.document.forms[0]; UpdatePartRow(); chkKeepSubmitPR(); if (doc.OrgMatrixYes.value == &quot;Y&quot;) { VerifyDeptOrgMatrix(); } return false;" href="">
```

[image]

You can access the nodeList by index e.g.

```
nodeList.item(0).Click
nodeList.item(0).FireEvent "onclick"
```

Comment: So I modified the VBA code to include: 'Dim nodeList As Object
Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("a[onclick*='UpdatePartRow']")'  and I set the node list:  HTMLDoc.all.CommodityMainSub.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B17")
     Set nodeList = HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll("a[onlick*='UpdatePartRow']")
     nodeList.Item(0).Click
    nodeList.Item(0).FireEvent "onclick"  It is still not giving me the result I am hoping for of "clicking" on the button.  Am I messing something up?  thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Any errors? And did you try replacing the 0 with 1 throughout?

Comment: It ran through the code in VBA with no errors popping up in VBA/Excel.  I have tried changing the 0 to 1.  I have also tried to change it to chkKeepSubmitPR instead of the UpdatePartRow.

Comment: I think I just found it!  But I made the website crash!  nodeList.item(0).FireEvent "onclick" needed to be nodeList.item(0).FireEvent ("onclick").  The webpage is now giving me an error saying "Quantity must be greater than zero, unable to complete request!".  So now I have to figure out why it is doing that and how I can fix that.  That you so much @QHarr.  I will let you know if I have more questions or the completed code once I solve it!

Comment: You shouldn't need () around "onclick" AFAIK. But good luck! Just don't try For Each loop with nodeList or inspecting in locals window - that will crash Excel.

Comment: It kept looping through the code.  I have separated out the onclick event from the main loop.  It still gave me an error.  The nodeList.Item(0).Click and FireEvent ("onclick") both did the same thing.  I deleted one and now no more error!  Now I just need to get it to do this multiple times over, but that is basically all code I have established.  Thank you all!

Comment: I don't know how it is being integrated into your full code. They do do the same thing in theory. The second is just when sometimes the first fails. Is it working now in principle?

Comment: It is working, with some quirks.  I had to strip out the login portion because it was causing an error and potentially created an exploit in the website.  So of the main data fields I have to enter a character in to actually populate when I submit.  Basically just making formatting and quality of life improvements and going to roll it out to the engineering teams on campus.